# Paging with FQL

Tags: facebook-fql

The graph api returns timestamps for the previous and the next pages for easy paging. How would one accomplish it with the FQL (for reading stream table posts)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can use **limit** and **offset** in FQL.

Comment: Looks like you can't now: "Each query of the stream table is limited to the previous 30 days or 50 posts, whichever is greater, however you can use time-specific fields such as created_time along with FQL operators (such as < or >) to retrieve a much greater range of posts." http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/